# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string CASE + CAST

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm a beginner to programming and I have this problem with a `CAST`.

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @adtdays INT

SELECT 
    @adtdays = CASE 
                  WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) > DATEPART(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, Day1)) 
                     THEN DATEPART(DAY, (DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/1/' + CAST(DATEPART(year, Day1) AS VARCHAR) AS DATE)))) 
                     ELSE 0 
               END 
FROM 
    ProgProdAlpidi 
WHERE 
    ProductCode  = 'PRODUCT CODE'
```

I get the following error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Could someone please help me?

Ok sorry im new,,, the desired result should be  :

If the current month is greater than the month of the "Day1 field" then
  Remove one day to current month, 1, current year.
  That will bring me the last day of the previous month...

that will be something like '4/30/2017'

first row is columnHeader second is first the row of my table...

```
ProductCode     MY  Vehicle Project Dest    Line   Day1     Day2    Day3
PRODUCT CODE    MY  VEHICLE PROJECT DEST.   LIN    42826    42827   42828
```

but seems the conversion im trying to do is wrong...

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I believe the part of the code causing the error is `DATEPART(MONTH,CONVERT(DATETIME,Day1))`.  What are you trying to achieve with this line?

Comment: i already added the desired result

Comment: The more I look at this I wonder if some of your values in the `day1` field simply aren't valid dates.

Comment: there you go.. hope that helps me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the Data Type of your `Day1` column in the database table? If it is an `INT` your query should work. If, however, it is something like `NVARCHAR` or `VARCHAR` then you will get the error that you are reporting above.

Comment: Thanks Breaking Bad its float and i made a SELECT to check if it works and it worked well... so i think its something else...